# A morphism which is not a comorphism of a regular map

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In the lecture, we dealt with morphisms, comorphisms and regular maps. The professor then brought the following example:

> Let $U$ and $V$ be quasi-affine sets over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\psi \colon \mathbb{C}[V] \to \mathbb{C}[U]$ be a morphism of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras. Then it is not hard to find an example where $\psi$ is not the comorphism $\phi^{\star}$ of a regular map $\phi \colon U \to V$.

I am struggling with this a while but can't find an example. I would be greatly appreciated for a hint or a solution.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Well, these things had better not be isomorphic to affine sets. Do you know any such varieties?

Comment: Hm, perhaps $V = \mathbb{A}_k^1 \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: That's isomorphic to the zero set of $xy - 1$ in the plane, unfortunately!

Comment: I have no idea.. any further hint?

Comment: The usual example is $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ with a point (the origin, say) deleted. You want to check that the ring of regular functions on this thing is $k[x,y]$ and then argue that it can't be isomorphic to an affine variety. This is a subtle thing.

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Time will tell.**

Consider the quasi-affine set $V = \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus\{(0,0)\}$, then $\mathbb{C}[V] = \mathbb{C}[\mathbb{A}^2]$. Further let $U = \mathbb{A}^2$, then $i \colon V \to U$ is a natural inclusion and $i^* \colon \mathbb{C}[U] \to \mathbb{C}[V]$ with $f \mapsto f_{\vert V}$ is an isomorphism. Define $\alpha = (i^*)^{-1}$. 
Let $\varphi \colon U \to V$ be a regular map and assume that $\alpha = \varphi^*$ is the comoprhism. We notice $i \circ \varphi \colon U \to U$ is a regular map. Apply $^*$- operator on $i \circ \varphi$
one obtain $(i \circ \varphi)^* = \varphi^* \circ i^* = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{C}[U]}$. By applying $^*$ again we get $i \circ \varphi  = ((i \circ \varphi)^*)^* = \mathrm{id}^{*}_{\mathbb{C}[U]} = \mathrm{id}_{U}$. But this is a contradiction since $i$ is not surjective.

I think this proof is correct. Did i made a mistake?